# Balls and bins (the power of two choices)

Tags: probability, balls-in-bins

Still balls into bins.

Suppose there are N balls and N bins, with the power of two choices, i.e., for each ball, randomly select two bins and place the ball into the bin with least loads.

What's the probability for the maximum bin to have more than k balls?

Just want the expression between Probability, N and k.

Any more ideas?

Thanks,

Comment: What do you mean by, "with the power of two choices"?

Comment: See: http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15859-f04/www/scribes/lec10.pdf

Comment: @JonasMeyer, that means each time randomly picking up two bins and placing the ball into least loaded bins

Comment: @Maazul, Hi, kinda of lost in the proof, since it prove with high probability, not with an expression. For the rough analysis, it is not exact probability. Does that mean for the same maiximum bin probability, the larger the N is, the larger k is?

Comment: Yes the proof implies that $k$ and $N$ are directly related for the same maximum bin probability but $k$ changes ridiculously slowly compared to $N$ in that case.

Comment: @Maazul My statement about k will increase with N increasing is correct?

Comment: Most probably, though a direct rigorous expression would make the judgment conclusive. Wait for the answers.

Comment: Anyone can have any ideas on proving this?